# How to enforce maxlength in scrolledittext in openlaszlo?

Tags: openlaszlo, lzx

Recently i was trying to create a scrollable edit text in openlaszlo. But for some reason maxlength property is not working. Any idea like why its not working. Is it a bug?.

I am doing it now in an alternate  way. Is there any better approach?

```
<canvas debug="true">
<include href="incubator/scrolledittext.lzx" /> 

<handler name="oninit">
canvas.answer.setAttribute('width',200);

this.answer.setAttribute('maxlength',20);

</handler>


    <scrolledittext  name="answer" x="20" y="20"  >
    <handler name="ontext">
        //this.setAttribute(maxlength,20);  
    Debug.write("greater1",this.text);  
    if(this.text.length > 20){
        var textContent = this.text;
        textContent = textContent.substring(0,20);
        updateText(textContent);
    }

    </handler>  

    <method name="updateText" args="a">
        Debug.write("UpdateText");
        this.setAttribute('text',a);        
    </method>   
    </scrolledittext>
</canvas>
```

Comment: Do you have some sample code? Which text input class are you using, <edittext>? Also, which OpenLaszlo version and run-time are you using?

Comment: Note: This bug existed in OpenLaszlo 4.0.3 DHTML run-time but is flagged as fixed here: http://jira.openlaszlo.org/jira/browse/LPP-4747

Comment: @Kmeixner: I have added a code snippet. I am using 4.9 and swf10 runtime.

Comment: @Kmeixner:I have added a code snippet. I am using 4.9 and swf10 runtime

Comment: Based on Andre's comment in the JIRA issue, it should be working in DHTML. Do you see that behavior in the DHTML runtime only? There shouldn't be a problem in SWFx runtimes. Maybe the events have changed for some browsers. Which browsers are causing the problem?

Comment: @RajuBitter: I checked in firefox and safari windows.